# how to get the posted data in c#

Tags: asp.net, post, webmethod

I use ajax in my applicataion, and I have to use the `$.post` method.

Normally, the data sent to server are key-value paires. I can get them through:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryPara['name'];
....
```

But in some cases, the data to be sent to the server does not contain the name.

It is just a xml segments.

Like this:

```
var data='<data>xxxxx<data>';
$.post('http://server/service.asmx/test',data,function(){
  //callback
},'xml');
```

Then How can I get the data in my webmethod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to use 'json' dataType to pass data to the web-method.

Have a look at sample:

Service.asmx

---

```
[ScriptService]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/testapp/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService{
   [WebMethod]
   public int Square(int no){ return no * no;}
}
```

and JavaScript code to request this *webmethod*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "service.asmx/Square",
            data: "{no: 10}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Result :" + data.d);
            },
            error: function (src,type,msg) {
                alert(msg); //open JavaScript console for detailed exception cause
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="Square" />
</body>
```

Comment: I mean get the data in the server side

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if asp.net can do that. But you could always provide a name like this:

```
var data= { data: '<data>xxxxx<data>'};
$.post('http://server/service.asmx/test',data,function(){
  //callback
},'xml');
```

Then at the server you can access by the

```
var data = Request.Params("data");
```